# In Azure Devops Classic Release Pipelines, How can I deploy all pipelines with a single click oruse a job to trigger all release pipelines (Linux agnt

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have Multiple classic Release pipelines in ADO that I want to deploy all at once. There is a custom task in marketplace but that doesnt work for a Linux agent. I am not using stages. I have created folders and in each folder I have 10 pipelines. Basically each folder has pipelines that create a new environment with all Infra. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Azure Devops Classic Release Pipelines, How can I deploy all pipelines with a single click oruse a job to trigger all release pipelines (Linux agnt

**Update:**

> I want to use only classic. An where shall i put this script. Should i
> create a new pipeline and add powershell task or for every pipeline
> shall i add this powershell task. sorry I am new to this

You could add a PowerShell task to create multiple releases for different release definition by [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/Releases/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0
```

Sample powershell script to create releases as below:

```
#Define the variable and enter the release definition id that you want to trigger. For example, I want to manually trigger release pipelines 1 and 2 at once.

$ReleaseDefinitionID = 1,2

ForEach ($ID in $ReleaseDefinitionID)
{
Write-host "ID is" $ID

$token = "pat"   
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=5.0"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$JSON = @"
{
  "definitionId": $ID
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON

}
```

You could use the REST API [create release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/Releases/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to deploy a new release.

`POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1`

See below example in powershell script:

See steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get Personal access token(PAT).

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1"

$PAT= "Personal access token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$body= '{
    "definitionId": 3
    }'

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Besides, in order to trigger all release pipelines, you could try to create YAML pipeline with parameters, like:

Main.yaml file:

```
jobs:
  - template: TriggerReleases.yaml
    parameters: 
      listOfEnvs:
        - "29" #The Id of the release definition Id list.
        - "28"  
        - "27"
```

TriggerReleases.yaml:

```
parameters:
  - name: listOfEnvs
    type: object
    default: []


jobs:
- ${{ each env in parameters.listOfEnvs }}:
    - job: Queue_${{ env }}_job1
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps: |
        # scripts to invoke REST API to trigger release pipeline.
```

You could check the document [Solving the looping problem in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/) for some more details.

Comment: I want to use only classic. An where shall i put this script. Should i create a new pipeline and add powershell task or for every pipeline shall i add this powershell task. sorry I am new to this

Comment: @Anonymouus, If you want to use only classic, you could create create a new pipeline and add Inline powershell task to add above scripts to achieve that. Check my update answer for some more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have one more question. How can I arrange this to deploy in a particular order. ReleaseDefinintionID= 5,8,9,2,3 etc . Because pipelines are dependent on each other. I have tried ID=3,2 but 2 deployed first and then 3

Comment: @Anonymouus, if you are using private agent, hen there should be multiple agents in your agent pool. At this time you need to add demands in your release pipeline. If you are using hosted agent, it seems difficult to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you. I just created multiple powershell tasks with def id's so that they will deploy serially